# What is the different between Dijsktra's algorithm and KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am implementing machine learning software and in my case, I am using K-nearest neighbour classifier to get the task done. 
 
So far, I am trying to understand how Dijkstra's algorithm that has been used to solve salesman travel problem is different from K-nearest neighbour algorithm?

Comment: How are they _similar_ ? The naive answer here would be _everything_.

Comment: what I mean that Dijsktra algo. is used to find the nearest neighbour as same as k-nearest neighbour algo.

Comment: They're totally unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the different between Dijsktra's algorithm and KNN?

Almost everything.

**$k$ nearest neighbor is a classification algorithm**. It stores a list of `[(features1, label1), (features2, label2), ..., (features-n, label-n)]`. When it gets a new item `features` it calculates the distance to each of the $n$ stored items. It finds the $k$ closest ones. It returns the label which is most often in those $k$ examples.

**Dijkstras algorithm is a graph search algorithm.** It takes a graph $G = (V, E)$, a start node $s \in V$ and a target node $t \in V$ as input and returns the shortest path (v_1, \dots, v_n) with $v_1, \dots, v_n \in V$ from $s$ to $t$.

(You might be interested in [the label correction algorithm](https://martin-thoma.com/label-correction-algorithm/), a generalization of Dijkstras algorithm)

### How they can be related. Somehow.

$k$ nearest neighbor can also operate on graphs. If you have a graph-like structure and your distance measure is e.g. the number of hops from a node, then you would use breadth first search.